# Why does typedef struct produce a link failure

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

So I have a piece of code that looks like this.

```
typedef struct {
  int foo;
  int bar;
  void foobar(int, char*);
} mystruct;
```

and

```
void mystruct::foobar(int x, char* y) { return; }
```

and

```
mystruct obj;
obj.foobar(17, "X");
```

This all compiles, links and runs perfectly. Except when it doesn't. On one compiler it works, and on another compiler (Android GCC) it fails with a link error: unsatisfied reference.

If I change it like this, it compiles and links.

```
struct mystruct {
  int foo;
  int bar;
  void foobar(int, char*);
};
```

I think I kind of know why, but I can't explain it properly and I can't find it in the standard. Can anyone explain it to me and find the proper reference?

Edit: I thought it was pretty obvious to all concerned that this is C++ code. I tagged it; function in a struct is not valid C; but just to be clear the file has a CPP extension and the compiler treats it as C++.

Edit: an answerer noticed that the call is a literal and therefore const, but the arg is non-const. This is not a critical factor because (a) the compiler passed it (b) the linked failed regardless of argument types.

Edit: My theory was that this is related to anonymous struct types passed to the linker so that declaration and call compiled separately did not match. It seems this may not be correct, in which case it may just be a subtle compiler bug.

Edit: out of curiosity, can anyone reproduce this behaviour? The actual compiler is Android NDK, recent download, and whatever version of GCC comes with that. If other compilers do/do not have this problem, that could be the answer.

Comment: The problem with your theory is that C++ linkers typically do not care about types at all. However, they do need the ability to refer to member `foobar`. For that purpose ("linkage purposes") it doesn't matter exactly which name is used, as long as it's consistent. You should have 2 .o files mentioning `foobar`, one defining it and one needing it. What are the **exact** mangled names used for `foobar` ?

Comment: Yes, by 'types' I meant 'mangled type names' as passed to the linker. Sorry, I have no idea how to answer your question. This is ADT/NDK running on Windows and it's all a black box. There are *.o binaries and there are *.o.d, but nothing that looks like a map. If there are compiler switches to make one, I don't know what they would be. I was kind of hoping this was something I didn't need to know.:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm thinking it's a compiler bug. The following more extreme example is still OK:

```
typedef struct { void f(); } f;
void f::f() { }
```

From [GCC buglist](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-bugs/2005-01/msg00266.html). I.e. you're allowed to use a typedef name to define a member function, even when that member function has the same name as the typedef.

Comment: it's not about a member having the same name as the class, is the 'class' being a `typedef anonymous struct` and not a class name.

Comment: @bolov: Which is **exactly** how the class in my example is defined too.

Comment: yes, but your explanation emphasizes on method having the same name as the class/typedef. The OP doesn't have anything like that. Anyway, it might be just me interpreting your words.

Comment: @bolov: That's because the method proves that the compiler can't internally name the struct `f` (or `mystruct` in the original example). IIRC, this was historically done in the earliest C++ compilers.

Comment: Ok I see now, but that wasn't clear (at least for me) from your answer. You could add this clarification to your answer.

Comment: It may be a compiler bug, but not this one. The typdef name and member name are not the same.

Comment: @david.pfx: That's an irrelevant detail. The point is that the GCC team believes it's OK to use the typedef name when defining a member function.

Comment: @MSalters: no, my reading of that bug and the standard is that the above code should not compile. The code is wrong; the compiler should not allow it. In the sample code I provided the code is OK (as far as I can tell), but does not link. Totally different scenario.

Comment: @david.pfx: The bug report says: "incorrectly rejects the following valid code (example)". How do you read that as "the following code is **invalid** ?

Comment: @MSalters: OK, rewind: like bolov, I thought you meant this bug was relevant, and I was trying (and failing) to show why it isn't. If you had made it clear this is a different bug and only the sample code is of interest, I would have agreed.

Comment: After some more investigation, yes, I think it's a compiler bug. Thanks everyone for the great contributions.

Answer (score 4):

C++11, 9.3/5

> If the definition of a member function is lexically outside its class definition, the member function name shall be qualified **by its class name** using the `::` operator.

In the first example, `mystruct` isn't the class name.

Comment: I think this is covered under the "for linkage purposes" rule.

Comment: @mike: it seems to me that S7.1.3 and S8 together say that a typedef-name is a class name for this purpose. I can't find an example.

Comment: @MSalters: well spotted. S7.1.3/9 says the typedef-name is the class name for linkage purposes. I'm starting to think this could be a compiler bug and not actually correct behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Basically the own name of the struct is on the first line before the { bracket. The last word is an other name to which is renamed by typedef.

Also it needs to use so:

```
typedef struct mystruct{int a;int b;void foobar(int,char*)} othername;
void mystruct::foobar(int,char*){}
```

Comment: If you claim it **needs** to, please provide the rule which says it must. It's clear that your version is **allowed**, but it's unclear whether the original form is **disallowed** (and if so, why)

Comment: This is a useful line of experimentation that I hadn't thought about. It still doesn't explain why the code compiles but fails to link.

Comment: There are a lot of compiler standards. The most known are Ansi C and the original C++, but the compiler and linker applications in use follow their own standards, with many simplified features in addition

Comment: @Aak: The original ANSI C standard (1989) was superseded by ISO C in 1990, and since then all C and C++ standards have come from ISO (WG14 and WG21 respectively). The main additional standard is POSIX, and it defers to ISO C. Still, feel free to quote whatever other standard you think should apply.

Comment: @MSalters: So the struct, which contains methods, is in fact a class, then follows a c++ standard. There a class definition is: class <ClassName> {...} <AliasName>; and an outer method definition is allowed as ClassName::methodname(..){}, and can't so AliasName::methodname(..){}

Comment: @Aak: _A_ definition. Not _the only possible_ definition. And that `<AliasName>` would define an **object** of type `<ClassName>` instead of an alias. You'd define an alias with `typedef` or `using`.

Answer (score 1):

The idiom of an anonymous struct in a typedef is one I used to use frequently when I first learnt C. For example the following lines are a valid description of a type in C

```
typedef struct
{
   char * characters;
   int length;
} String;
```

If gcc chokes on this then gcc is wrong.

Comment: It doesn't. The problem is the function call, not the struct itself.

Answer (score -2):

Seems you are mixing C and C++. First, if you want the code to be C++, then you definitely must have:

```
void foobar(int, const char*);
```

because "X" is of type (const char *), not (char *).

Second, If you want your code to be C, then you can't use a function in the structure. Only pointers to function are allowed in C. So,

```
typedef struct {
    void (*foo)(void);
} X;
```

Your first code is valid in C++ code, but it is probably something different then you really want.

typedef struct { ... } A; in C++ is a no-name structure with a typedef. It's something like:

```
 struct A {
     void foo();
 }
 typedef A B;
 void B::foo() { }
```

I don't think this would be a valid C++ construction. Removing "A" you got your code exactly:

```
 typedef struct {
     void foo();
 } B;
 void B::foo() { }
```

Comment: Sorry, but "I don't think this would be valid" is just an opinion. It's definitely allowed to mix C and C++ style, even if it's a bad idea. C++ still allows unnamed classes, and "names for linkage purposes".

Comment: struct A {}; tyepdef A B; B::foo() {} - is not valid C++ neither C code!

Comment: void foo(char *c) {} foo(""); - is valid C code, but not C++ code. So, valid C code doesn't have to be a valid C++ code.

Comment: FYI, C++03 has an implicit conversion from string literal to `char*`. It's deprecated though, and (for example) `-Wwritable-strings` on GCC warns for it.

Comment: The const-ness of the 2nd arg is not critical. I experimented with multiple kinds of args to no effect. I used literals here to keep the code short. It's typedef vs not typedef that is the critical difference.

Comment: @smrt28: have you asked your compiler? It looks valid to me.

Comment: Yes, it seems char * c = "" is just a warning. Hmm, interesting. However, the rest of my answer is exactly the answer for your question.